# PortedDuff Clear does not work under Android 2.3.6.Draws with black

Tags: android, android-canvas, porter-duff

Now I have tried about 6-7 variations of this code, but something just isn't right. I have almost the same code (just the ondraw part a bit different, ready to catch finger input) and it works. but here it just draws with black. I need to create a timer, similar to a clock. So i draw a circle with red, and then according to the elapsed time it will draw with PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR over that circle to delete from it.
Now I usually don't do this, but I'm kind of desperate and need a answer quickly, so I will post all the code from my classes, because sincerely I don't get what I'm doing wrong, so my mistake could be anywhere in my activity or View:

This is the custom View I created to add to my relative layout:

```
 public TimeView(Context mContext, Bitmap bitmapgol, Canvas canvas) {
    super(mContext);
    context = mContext;
    this.canvas = canvas;
    displayWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    displayHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    try {
        setBitmap(bitmapgol, bitmapgol.getConfig());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    LogService.log("", "density" + density + " | W: " + displayWidth + " | H : " + displayHeight);
    float middle = displayWidth / 2;
    rectF = new RectF(middle / 2 - 32 * density, middle / 2 - 52 * density, middle + middle / 2 + 32 * density, middle + middle / 2 + 12 * density);
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setAlpha(0);
    paint.setXfermode(pd);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    } else {
        LogService.log("", "NULLLLLLLL");
    }
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.timer_clock));
    paint.setAlpha(255);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
    int circleRadius = (int) (110 * density);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY(), circleRadius, paint);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.setAlpha(0);
    paint.setXfermode(pd);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, -90, 360 - percent, true, paint);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    paint.setAlpha(255);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setTextSize(25 * density);
    if (time != -1) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (red) {
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
        int hours = (int) (time / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        int hoursMod = (int) (time % (60 * 60 * 1000));
        int min = (int) (hoursMod / (1000 * 60));
        int minMod = (int) (hoursMod % (1000 * 60));
        int seconds = (int) (minMod / 1000);
        if (hours != 0) {
            String timeS = hours + "h " + min + "m " + seconds + "s ";
            drawDigit(canvas, (int) (25 * density), rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY(), paint.getColor(), timeS);

        } else if (min != 0) {
            String timeS = min + "m " + seconds + "s ";
            drawDigit(canvas, (int) (25 * density), rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY(), paint.getColor(), timeS);

        } else {
            String timeS = seconds + "s ";
            drawDigit(canvas, (int) (25 * density), rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY(), paint.getColor(), timeS);

        }
    } else {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        String timeS = "Finished";
        drawDigit(canvas, (int) (25 * density), rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY(), paint.getColor(), timeS);
    }
    invalidate();
}

public void setTime(long millisUntilFinished) {
    percent = millisUntilFinished * ratio;
    invalidate();
}

public void setFullTime(int timeToCount) {
    ratio = (float) (360f / timeToCount);
}

public void setTimeForText(long time, boolean red) {
    this.time = time;
    this.red = red;
}

private void drawDigit(Canvas canvas, int textSize, float cX, float cY, int color, String text) {
    Paint tempTextPaint = new Paint();
    tempTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    tempTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    tempTextPaint.setColor(color);
    tempTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

    float textWidth = tempTextPaint.measureText(text);
    canvas.drawText(text, cX - (textWidth / 2), cY + (textSize / 2), tempTextPaint);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap.Config targetConfig) throws Exception { // se cheama in Paint Activity sa se seteze bitmapu
    LogService.log("", "bitmap1 : " + bitmap);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sample/temp.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    file.setWritable(true);
    file.setReadable(true);
    file.setExecutable(true);
    randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    int bWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int bHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer map = channel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, bWidth * bHeight * 4);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(map);
    bitmap.recycle();
    this.bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bWidth, bHeight, targetConfig);
    map.position(0);
    this.bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(map);
    channel.close();
    randomAccessFile.close();
    LogService.log("", "bitmap1 : " + this.bitmap);

}
```

This is the activity that adds the TimeView to it:

```
     public class ActivityRemainingTime extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private final static String TAG = ActivityRemainingTime.class.getSimpleName();

    TimeView timeview;
    CountDownTimer count;
    int reminder;// va fi ales
    RelativeLayout timeExtend;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    AlarmReceiver alarmReceiver;
    int timeToCount = 1;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private Timer t;
    RelativeLayout timeV;
    OnValueChangeListener valuechangedListener;
    int timeAdded = 0;
    NumberPicker hoursNP, minutesNP;
    Bundle b;
    private Bitmap bitmapgol;
    private int hourOfDay;
    private ArrayList<Taxes> taxes = new ArrayList<Taxes>();
    private RelativeLayout loader;
    private long millistofinish = 0;

    // Define the listener for the slide in/out animations
    private Animation.AnimationListener animListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Get the text off the "new parking" text view
            String newParkingText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_new_parking_tv)).getText().toString();
            // Check to see whether the the animation was a slide in or slide out
            if (newParkingText.contentEquals(getString(R.string.time_new_parking))) {
                // It was a slide OUT
                // Show the remaining time TV

            } else {
                // It was a slide IN
                // Instantiate the intent and attach the required values to it
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityRemainingTime.this, ActivityPayment.class);
                intent.putExtra("extended", true);
                intent.putExtra("timeAdded", timeAdded);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.ACTIVITY_PAYMENT);
                LogService.log(TAG, "timeadded is when entering: " + timeAdded);

                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile;

    private int displayWidth;

    private int displayHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_remaining_time);
        LogService.log(TAG, "onCreate");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("intent_myaction_alarm");
        displayWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        displayHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        // Set the on click listeners for the buttons
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.time_new_parking)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.time_extend_time)).setOnClickListener(this);
        loader = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_loader_container);

        // Initialize the title bar
        TitleBarHandler.initTitleBar(this, "Munsterlingen|Switzerland", false, true);
        WSCalls.webserviceCallParkingCharges(loader, ActivityRemainingTime.this, new GetBackFromWS() {

            @Override
            public void success() {
            }

            @Override
            public void success(ArrayList<Taxes> taxes) {
                if (ActivityRemainingTime.this.taxes != null) {
                    ActivityRemainingTime.this.taxes.clear();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < taxes.size(); i++) {
                    Taxes tax = new Taxes(taxes.get(i).getPrice(), taxes.get(i).getMinutes() - (Constants.timeToCount / 60));
                    ActivityRemainingTime.this.taxes.add(tax);
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         * Configure the number pickers and at the same time disable the softkeyboard on them
         */
        // Get number picker references
        hoursNP = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.select_hour_number_picker);
        minutesNP = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.select_min_number_picker);
        // Initialize pickers with values
        Tools.initializeNumberPicker(hoursNP, 0, 14, 1);
        Tools.initializeNumberPicker(minutesNP, 0, 59, 1);
        // Disable softkeyboard
        // hoursNP.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        // minutesNP.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

        timeV = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.timeViewLayout);
        valuechangedListener = new OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                calculateTime();
            }

        };
        hoursNP.setOnValueChangedListener(valuechangedListener);
        minutesNP.setOnValueChangedListener(valuechangedListener);
        EditText hoursInput = Tools.findInput(hoursNP);
        EditText minutesInput = Tools.findInput(minutesNP);
        hoursInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        minutesInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            timeToCount = b.getInt("timeToCount", 0);
            reminder = b.getInt("reminder", 600);
            LogService.log(TAG, "hei time to count: " + Constants.timeToCount + " |new time to count| " + timeToCount);
            if (timeToCount != 0) {
                Constants.timeToCount = timeToCount;
                PersistentUtil.setTimeToCount(ActivityRemainingTime.this, timeToCount);
            } else if (timeToCount == 0) {
                timeToCount = Constants.timeToCount;
            }

            LogService.log(TAG, "bundle NOT null: " + reminder + " || " + Constants.timeToCount);
            b = null;
        } else {
            LogService.log(TAG, "bundle null");
        }
        LogService.log(TAG, "Spotname: " + PersistentUtil.getSelectedSpot(ActivityRemainingTime.this));
        initTimeView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LogService.log(TAG, "onPause");
        if (count != null) {
            count.cancel();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LogService.log(TAG, "onResume");
        if (b == null) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "resume bundle null");
            Constants.timeToCount = PersistentUtil.getTimeToCount(ActivityRemainingTime.this);
            Constants.exactTime = PersistentUtil.getExactTime(ActivityRemainingTime.this);
            timeview.setFullTime(Constants.timeToCount);
        }
        /*
         * Reset the footer to go back to default states
         */
        // Set the text of the
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_new_parking_tv)).setText(getString(R.string.time_new_parking));
        // Show the time displayed above the footer
        // Reset the number pickers to zero
        hoursNP.setValue(0);
        minutesNP.setValue(0);

        /*
         * Reinitialize the reminder value
         */
        // Get the index of the beed which was selected -1 or in interval [1, 5]
        int selectedIndex = PersistentUtil.getSelectedBeed(this);
        // Get the time of the beed
        reminder = Tools.getSeconds(0, Integer.parseInt(ActivityMain.getTimeFromBeedIndex(selectedIndex)));
        // Re-initialize the timer view
        LogService.log(TAG, "on resume Time to count: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - Constants.exactTime) - (((Constants.timeToCount * 1000) - (reminder * 1000)))));
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - Constants.exactTime) < ((Constants.timeToCount * 1000) - (reminder * 1000))) {
            initAlarmReceiver((Constants.timeToCount * 1000) - (reminder * 1000));
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - Constants.exactTime > 1000) {
            final float begin = (System.currentTimeMillis() - PersistentUtil.getExactTime(ActivityRemainingTime.this));
            LogService.log(TAG, "Time EXACT starting time: " + PersistentUtil.getExactTime(ActivityRemainingTime.this));
            LogService.log(TAG, "Time: " + begin);
            LogService.log(TAG, "TimeToCount: " + Constants.timeToCount * 1000);
            if (begin < (PersistentUtil.getTimeToCount(ActivityRemainingTime.this) * 1000)) {
                LogService.log(TAG, "Countdown timer: " + ((Constants.timeToCount * 1000) - begin));
                timeToCount((int) ((Constants.timeToCount * 1000) - begin));
            } else {
                LogService.log(TAG, "Timer initiated in ELSE");
                t = new Timer();
                t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                if (timeview == null) {
                                    bitmapgol = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayWidth, displayHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
                                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
                                    try {
                                        Bitmap bit = setMuttable(icon);
                                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bit);
                                        timeview = new TimeView(ActivityRemainingTime.this, bitmapgol, canvas);
                                        tryPorterDuff();
                                        timeV.addView(timeview);
                                        timeview.setFullTime(Constants.timeToCount);
                                        timeV.bringToFront();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                timeview.setTime(0);
                                timeview.setTimeForText(-1, true);
                                final float begin = (System.currentTimeMillis() - Constants.exactTime);
                                int millisUntilFinished = (int) -((Constants.timeToCount * 1000) - begin);
                                LogService.log(TAG, "intrat la millisUntilFinished" + millisUntilFinished);
                                if (millisUntilFinished < 2100000000) {
                                    timeview.setTimeForText(millisUntilFinished, true);                                 
                                } else {
                                    LogService.log(TAG, "intrat in else la timertask");
                                    Constants.timeToCount = -1;
                                    Constants.exactTime = -1;
                                    PersistentUtil.setTimeToCount(ActivityRemainingTime.this, Constants.timeToCount);
                                    PersistentUtil.setExactTime(ActivityRemainingTime.this, Constants.exactTime);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            Tools.showCloseAppConfirmation(this);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.ACTIVITY_PAYMENT:
            if (resultCode == Constants.CLOSE_ACTIVITY)
                finish();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.time_new_parking:

            if (((TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_new_parking_tv)).getText().toString().contentEquals(getString(R.string.time_new_parking_save))) {
                if (inputDataIsValid()) {
                    collapse((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_extend_slider));
                }
            } else {
                PersistentUtil.setTimerStarted(this, false);

                startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class));
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
                finish();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.time_extend_time:

            if (((TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_new_parking_tv)).getText().toString().contentEquals(getString(R.string.time_new_parking_save))) {
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.extend_arrow)).setImageResource(R.drawable.disclosure_arrow);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_new_parking_tv)).setText(getString(R.string.time_new_parking));
                collapse((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_extend_slider));
            } else {
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.extend_arrow)).setImageResource(R.drawable.disclosure_arrow_down);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_new_parking_tv)).setText(getString(R.string.time_new_parking_save));
                expand((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_extend_slider));
            }

            break;
        }

    }

    private void timeToCount(int timec) {
        count = new CountDownTimer(timec, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                millistofinish = millisUntilFinished;
                if (timeview == null) {
                    bitmapgol = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayWidth, displayHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
                    try {
                        Bitmap bit = setMuttable(icon);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bit);
                        timeview = new TimeView(ActivityRemainingTime.this, bitmapgol, canvas);
                        tryPorterDuff();
                        timeV.addView(timeview);
                        timeview.setFullTime(Constants.timeToCount);
                        timeV.bringToFront();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                timeview.setTime(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timeview.setTimeForText(millisUntilFinished, false);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                timeview.setTimeForText(-1, true);
                timeview.setTime(0);
                LogService.log(TAG, "Alarma: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                millistofinish = 0;
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void initTimeView() {
        LogService.log(TAG, "---------------------------------------Init TIme VIEW, time to count: " + Constants.timeToCount);
        LogService.log(TAG, "---------------------------------------Init TIme VIEW, time to count: " + PersistentUtil.getTimeToCount(ActivityRemainingTime.this));
        bitmapgol = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayWidth, displayHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
        try {
            Bitmap bit = setMuttable(icon);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bit);
            timeview = new TimeView(ActivityRemainingTime.this, bitmapgol, canvas);
            tryPorterDuff();
            timeV.addView(timeview);
            timeview.setFullTime(Constants.timeToCount);
            timeV.bringToFront();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (reminder != 0) {
            timeToCount(Constants.timeToCount * 1000);
            LogService.log(TAG, "Reminder != 0" + reminder);
            Constants.exactTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PersistentUtil.setTimeToCount(ActivityRemainingTime.this, Constants.timeToCount);
            PersistentUtil.setExactTime(ActivityRemainingTime.this, Constants.exactTime);
            initAlarmReceiver((Constants.timeToCount * 1000) - (reminder * 1000));
        } else {
            LogService.log(TAG, "Reminder == 0" + reminder);
        }
    }

    private void tryPorterDuff() {
        try {
            Method setLayerTypeMethod = timeview.getClass().getMethod("setLayerType", new Class[] { int.class, Paint.class });
            setLayerTypeMethod.invoke(timeview, new Object[] { 1, null });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // Older OS, no HW acceleration anyway
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        findViewById(R.id.remaining_time_main).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background2);

    }

    private void initAlarmReceiver(int time) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityRemainingTime.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("intent_myaction_alarm");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ActivityRemainingTime.this, 1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ActivityRemainingTime.this.getSystemService(ActivityRemainingTime.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (Constants.exactTime + time), pendingIntent);
        LogService.log(TAG, "a fost initiat receiverul : " + (Constants.exactTime + time));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        LogService.log(TAG, "ondestroy");
        if (t != null) {
            t.cancel();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Used to animate a view expansion. Increase view from 0 to wrap content.
     * 
     * @param v
     */
    public void expand(final View v) {
        hoursNP.setOnValueChangedListener(valuechangedListener);
        minutesNP.setOnValueChangedListener(valuechangedListener);
        v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT : (int) (targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration((int) (targtetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }

    /**
     * Used to animate a view collapse. Reduce size from wrap content to 0.
     * 
     * @param v
     */
    public void collapse(final View v) {
        hoursNP.setOnValueChangedListener(null);
        minutesNP.setOnValueChangedListener(null);
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };      
        a.setDuration((int) (initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        a.setAnimationListener(animListener);
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if the user selected the minimum required minutes in order to extend the parking time
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private boolean inputDataIsValid() {

        // The parking time needs to be at least 10 minutes
        if (minutesNP.getValue() == 0 && hoursNP.getValue() == 0) {
            Tools.showInfoDialog(this, getString(R.string.main_validation_parking_time_title), getString(R.string.main_validation_parking_time_body));
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void calculateTime() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        hourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        LogService.log(TAG, "hourOfDay : " + hourOfDay + ": " + minOfDay);
        if (hourOfDay > 6 && hourOfDay < 20) {
            int hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursNP.getDisplayedValues()[hoursNP.getValue()]);
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesNP.getDisplayedValues()[minutesNP.getValue()]);
            if (hours == 14) {
                minutes = 0;
                minutesNP.setValue(0);
            }
            timeAdded = Tools.getMinutes(hours, minutes);
            int mintofinish = (int) (millistofinish / (1000 * 60));
            int timeto8 = 1200 - (hourOfDay * 60 + minOfDay + mintofinish);
            if (timeto8 < timeAdded) {
                LogService.log(TAG, "timp mai mare decat ora 8");
                timeAdded = timeto8;
            }
            String cost = getString(R.string.main_cost_header) + ": <b>";
            double chf;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            if (taxes.size() > 1) {
                if (timeAdded > taxes.get(0).getMinutes()) {
                    LogService.log(TAG, "------------");
                    chf = taxes.get(0).getMinutes() * (float) (taxes.get(0).getPrice() / 60f);
                    int minus = taxes.get(0).getMinutes();
                    for (int i = 1; i < taxes.size(); i++) {
                        if (timeAdded > taxes.get(i).getMinutes()) {
                            chf += ((taxes.get(i).getMinutes() - minus) * (float) (taxes.get(i).getPrice() / 60f));
                            minus = taxes.get(i).getMinutes();
                            LogService.log(TAG, "min: " + taxes.get(i).getMinutes() + " /price:" + taxes.get(i).getPrice() + " /minus:" + minus + " /chf: " + chf);
                        } else {
                            chf += ((timeAdded - minus) * (float) (taxes.get(i).getPrice() / 60f));
                            LogService.log(TAG, "min: " + timeAdded + " /price:" + taxes.get(i).getPrice() + " /minus:" + minus + " /chf: " + chf);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    LogService.log(TAG, "------------");
                } else {
                    chf = timeAdded * (float) (taxes.get(0).getPrice() / 60f);
                    LogService.log(TAG, "min: " + timeAdded + " /price:" + taxes.get(0).getPrice() + " /chf: " + chf);
                }
            } else {
                chf = timeAdded * (float) (taxes.get(0).getPrice() / 60f);
            }
            cost += df.format(chf);
            cost += "</b> ";
            cost += "CHF"; // TODO: replace with currency got from webservice       
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost)).setText(Html.fromHtml(cost));
            LogService.log(TAG, "timeadded: " + timeAdded);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap setMuttable(Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception { 
        File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/sample/temp.txt");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        int bWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        int bHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer map = channel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, bWidth * bHeight * 4);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(map);
        bitmap.recycle();
        Bitmap bit;
        bit = Bitmap.createBitmap(bWidth, bHeight, bitmap.getConfig());
        map.position(0);
        bit.copyPixelsFromBuffer(map);
        channel.close();
        randomAccessFile.close();
        return bit;

    }
}
```